# Archiving ASP.Net users with MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, archive

Are there best practices for archiving asp.net users when deleted using MembershipProvider?

Basically, what I want to accomplish is when I delete a user using for example MembershipProvider.DeleteUser("someusername@some.com", true), I want to be able to archive its profile.

Comment: What is your definition of Archiving? For example, move the deleted user to an archive table or add a `IsDeleted` column to a table?

Comment: Archive means to retain the data without physically deleting them from the database.  My first instinct is to save the data to another table.  And no, I refuse to add IsDeleted column to my_aspnet_users table.  Is my first instinct "best practice"?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just do `Membership.DeleteUser(username,true).` You might get a little prompt for adding a using directive on Membership. If you have it configured properly, you shouldn't need to be creating new `SimpleMembershipProvider` instance.

If you create it on the fly like that, you'll need to set connections on that object and configure it programmatically(it has no clue about the connection you created above). Usually people do that in web.config, but if you created the app using the forms authentication template, then you should have that taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since (as the name suggests) the Membership is based on Provider pattern, you can easily implement your's DeleteUser method with archiving capability.

For SqlMembershipProvider you can easily add Deleted bit column and customize aspnet_Users_DeleteUser stored procedure to not really delete user but just set this bit. Then also modify other sprocs for selecting etc so it is consistent. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx for overview.

Comment: I thought of providing my own implementation of DeleteUser method; however on the database, I'm getting a sense that I should not be altering the Membership tables.  So how do I get around this?

Comment: You can alter them in any way you need. In one of my projects we did big changes and all went good. Of course you need to know how it works. It is open exactly for this reason. It doesn't behave the way you want it? Change it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using legacy Membership provider, here are two solutions -

### Easy Way

Mark **aspnet_Membership** table's **IsApproved** column to **false**, so user won't be able to login.

If you want to do so, you need to modify **aspnet_Users_DeleteUser** store procedure to update **IsApproved** column instead of deleting user.

### Hard Way

As you said you do not want to add IsDeleted column to **aspnet_Users** table, create a new table to keep track of deleted users.

[image]

Here you also need to modify **aspnet_Users_DeleteUser** store procedure to insert **UserId** to **DeletedUsers** table instead of deleting user.

In addition, you need to modify **aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat** store procedure for login validation.

Comment: Thanks for the time and giving your input.  
Since I couldn't find a "standard practice", I implemented this by:

1. Add a new table (e.g. call it Archive table in a separate database).  I didn't want to modify in anyway the database created by the AspNetMembershipProvider.
2. Override the Delete method of the MembershipProvider.  Archive in the new table the records that have been deleted. 


That's it. Thanks!